# PHP Jquery select multiple file ready to upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I got a form with file upload fields along with others text field etc., I was thinking to allow user to select their upload files (maximum 3 files), can I achieve it with just share one file input box and display the selected file name under it before submit? can jquery do this? I had found lots of existing jquery library that has such function, but all will uploaded the files in real time before I validate others field and click submit to request ajax process.

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something like what you maybe need. When you click on the 'select files' and choose some files, it will show you a list of them. I used a jQuery. Here is the code:

```
<input type="file" id="test" multiple>
<div id="text"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#test').bind('change', function() {
    var files = this.files;
    var i = 0;
    for(; i < files.length; i++) {
      var filename = files[i].name + "<br />";
      $("#text").append(filename);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect but if you get _files[i] is undefined_ error, just change `i <= files` to `i < files`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was something like a typo or etc, already edited.

Comment: Also you can add `$("#text").html("");` before a 'for loop', so when you choose another items again, it will clear a list first.

Comment: but how will you also submit the filepath to the server for processing?

Comment: My answer is applied to a pure HTML form, so it is proceed with POST request with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and you can get files with `$_FILES['name-of-input']`. You can see an example how to handle files here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp but when you want to upload asynchronously, I recommend you this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload This question is about "handle files before upload". When you have troubles with handling uploaded files at server-side, you should consider posting an own question.